# ejecuta contenido de condición IF incluso no cumpliéndose la condición

Tags: php, poo

a ver si alguien logra sacarme de este debate existencial que estoy teniendo.
 Tengo el siguiente método de la clase Login que comprueba si los datos introducidos son correctos:

```
function probar(){
    $sql = 'SELECT usuario, pass FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario';
    $sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':usuario', $this->nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $test = $sentencia->execute();
    $result = $sentencia->fetch();

    if(password_verify($this->get_pass(), $result['pass'])){
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $this->get_nombre();
        header('Location: ../admin.php');
    }else{
        $test = 2;
    }
    return $test;
}
```

En el controlador tengo el siguiente mecanismo:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../model/Login.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$obj = new Login;
$obj->set_nombre($user);
$obj->set_pass($pass);
$exito = $obj->probar();

if($exito == 2){
    header('Location: ../login.php?p=2');
}elseif($exito == 0){
    header('Location: login.php?p=0');
}
```

}

Mi problema es que, aunque sea exitosa la validación en probar, siempre pasa por el primer condicional del controlador (if($exito == 2)).

Sabéis por qué puede pasar esto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que la validación en `probar()` es exitosa? Si lo fuera, habría una redirección, y por tanto, no tiene sentido ni un `return` ni esperar que el código devolverá el control a quien llamó a `probar()`, puesto que estás redirigiendo a `admin.php`.  Prueba a ponerlo así a ver qué pasa: `if(password_verify($this->get_pass(), $result['pass'])){
        $test=0;
    }else{
        $test = 2;
    }` ahí sí sabrás si valida o no realmente.

Comment: Genial Cedano!!!!
Sabía que la conexión era exitosa porque lo comprobé comentando parte del código y haciendo echo. Si pongo $test = 0 me llevaría al primer error, ya que al no poder realizarse la ejecución devolvería 0   $test = $sentencia->execute();   Pero claro, tu idea fue la correcta! lo que he hecho es poner $test = 1 si la verificación del pass era correcta y así funciona

Gracias!

Comment: Lo que sigo sin entender es que, si el execute es exitoso ya devuelve 1. Por lo que sigo sin saber por qué me ocurría eso...

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu duda. Como ya dije, si se cumpliera esto: `if(password_verify($this->get_pass(), $result['pass'])){` **el código redirigiría a `admin.php` y el control no volvería al contexto que llamó a `probar()` para hacer una verificación de `$test`**, no sé si me entiendes, ese es el problema principal de tu código, es incoherente por decirlo de alguna manera, porque haces llamadas que, en algunos casos no retornarían (por la redirección) y en otros sí. Si le das coherencia al código podrás entender su comportamiento.